# Preselect dropdown-menu option in Bootstrap according to the page browsed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a web site in PHP where index.php calls different webpages like this:

> index.php?page=cars

and then:

```
<html code>
<?php
$pagesOk = array('cars, 'boats', 'trucks);
...
if (in_array($_GET['page'], $pagesOk)) {
   require_once('pages/'.$page.'.php');
}
```

I also have a searchbox (populated with JQuery autocomplete) present in the top of the index.php file, so that it is accessible from all the subpages.

```
<nav class="searchbar input-group">
   <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
   <input class="reset" type="search" id="searchInput" autocomplete="none" data-clearButton >
   <button class="reset cd-nav-trigger" aria-label="Toggle menu"></button>
   <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <span id="search_concept">All content<span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu mode-recherche" role="menu" style="top: 10px !important; left: -10px !important">
          <li><a href="#cars">Cars</a></li>
          <li><a href="#boats">Boats</a></li>
          <li><a href="#trucks">Trucks</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#all">All content</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

I'd like now the dropdown-menu to be automatically selected to the current pages.

Meaning that if the user is on **index.php?page=boats**, the dropdown menu **Boats** is selected within the searchbox so that he can search only boats by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your page name then `selected` option based on `$page` name

[image]

here's full code including php:

```
<?php
    $pagesOk = array('cars','boats', 'trucks');
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if (in_array($page, $pagesOk)) {
        # do somthing
        # require_once('pages/'.$page.'.php');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">LOGO</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mynavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Pages</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Contacts</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <select class="form-select">
            <option>All content</option>
            <option <?=$page == 'cars' ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Cars</option>
            <option <?=$page == 'boats' ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Boats</option>
            <option <?=$page == 'trucks' ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Trucks</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <h3>Some body text</h3>
    <p>You can also include forms inside the navigation bar.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doing that with <select> is an easy solution but off topic. I need to keep those <ul><li> and do this with jquery

Comment: please share full code here or codepen.io